# Can a Pathfinder Society gunslinger craft ammunition?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-society

Gunslingers automatically gain the [Gunsmithing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/gunsmithing) feat at level 1, which allows them to craft ammunition at a reduced price.  This seems like a rather important feat.

Unfortunately, the [Guide to PFS Organized Play](http://paizo.com/products/btpy84k4?Guide-to-Pathfinder-Society-Organized-Play) says the following about crafting:

> Additionally, except for specific examples cited in this guide or the Pathfinder Society FAQ, the Craft skill is not legal for play and crafting of mundane items is not allowed in Pathfinder Society.

The "specific examples" in the document only refer to using Craft for your Day Job, and the [FAQ](http://paizo.com/pathfinderSociety/faq) only discusses Craft in the context of alchemists.

Do PFS gunslingers really have to buy ammo at full price?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://paizo.com/pathfinderSociety/resources

> Gunsmithing does not grant the ability to craft firearms, ammunition, or black powder. Rather, **it allows the purchase of bullets, pellets, black powder, and alchemical cartridges (with 1 rank in Craft [alchemy]) at the listed reduced price**, but does not grant a discount on the purchase of any firearm. Resold items gained through this feat are worth half the actual cost paid, not half the regular market value for the item. No PC can purchase a gun without this feat, even if they possess the Amateur Gunslinger or Exotic Weapon Proficiency (firearm) feats.

The part that specifically answers your question is in **bold**

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - thanks Colin!